# Should a viewport breakpoint affect outside of the breakpoint's area in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, breakpoints

Well, maybe the title of this question make no (or, little) sense. Here is details to my question:

If I am not wrong, in Twitter Bootstrap, ***-sm-*** means it is the breakpoint with `min-width: 576px` and `max-width: 767.98px`. For instance,

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
     /* ... */
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container,
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container-fluid,
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container-sm,
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container-md,
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container-lg,
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container-xl {
        -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
}
```

But some codes in **Twitter Bootstrap**'s `bootstrap.css` file I've noticed like this:

```css
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container,
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container-fluid,
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container-sm,
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container-md,
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container-lg,
    .navbar-expand-sm>.container-xl {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

and it seems that we're using `.navbar-expand-sm` for the devices with viewport size less than minimum width required for ***sm***. (it is not only for the case of `sm`)

I don't understand this mythology. Can you give e precious idea about this? what is exactly area of `sm` in **Twitter Bootstrap**?

Answer (score 0):

This part is only for the bootstrap Grid Sizing System.

They are considered `<576px` for Extra small devices, such as mobile phones.

`sm` is for small devices such as tablets, and the size starts at `≥576px` up to `<768px`. So Base on the fact that we have 5 sections of sizes in bootstrap, the other part will continue to grow up to 1200px for extra-large desktops.

Navbars have different sizing system which only have 4 sections, we don't have extra small for navbars so the last part is sm section. which is consider below 576.

Comment: That means class names like ` navbar-expand-sm ` have no effects for devices with viewport size less than 576px?  Then look at my question's last code snippet...

Comment: No, it just for bootstrap the grid system. They have different sizing for their components. like navbar, we have only 4 size section.

Comment: Sorry! I am not good at understanding quickly. 

Can you tell me which of the two lines of code given bellow affect on mobile  display: 



(1) .navbar-expand-sm > .container { padding-left: 0}
(2) .navbaqr-expand-md > .container {padding-left: 0}

I think, it should be (1) line. But it does, however (2)  and all I wanted to know from this quesition is why this (2) ? Does it not violet it's naming convention ?